# How handle confirmation dialog using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I try to find out how can I click on button "deactivate" . This is html code:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1328px; height: 1063px; z-index: 1001;"></div>

<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px none; height: auto; width: 640px; top: 737.4px; left: 173px;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-1">

    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <span id="ui-dialog-title-1" class="ui-dialog-title" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></span>
        <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="confirmDialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 134.133px; height: auto;">
        <span class="closeButton"></span>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <div class="buttonRow">
            <button class="negative cancel" type="button"></button>
            <button class="deactivate" type="button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I tried to click on this button  in this way:

```
@FindBy(className = "deactivate")
private WebElement deactivateButton;
WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(deactivateButton));
 deactivateButton.click();
```

But this doesn't help

Comment: Have a look at [Geb](http://gebish.org). It's a very helpful wrapper around the Java Selenium driver and makes interactions like this a lot easier to manage.

Comment: Is this a lightbox that pops up with JQuery UI? If you can provide a working snippet with all the JS libraries involved, it'll be easier to provide you with an answer, instead of trying to guess what's going on in your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **elementToBeClickable** please try with **visibilityOf** like below. It's much cleaner.:

```
WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(deactivateButton));
 deactivateButton.click();
```